# htaccess block domains from hotlinking images

Tags: .htaccess

I blocked some sites in the file but they keep comming on my server and asking for images that slow down my server how i can add a rule for them so they will see big red sign STOP HOTLINKING

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?somesite\.pl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?somesite\.pl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?somesite\.pl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?sklep.somesite\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mate try the below ,*

Following code will only allow the mentioned domain "alloweddomain.com" and block others from hot linking

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?alloweddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

The above code will allow *"Blank Referrers"*

**What is Blank Referrers ?**

Some visitors uses a personal firewall or antivirus program, that deletes the page referrer information sent by the web browser. Hotlink protection is based on this information. So if you choose not to allow blank referrers, you will block these users. You will also prevent people from directly accessing an image by typing in the URL in their browser.

Suppose if you don't want to allow *"Blank Referrers"* then use the following code mate

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?alloweddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Also if suppose you want to display a image like *"STOP HOTLINKING"* then use the below method

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?alloweddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ mydomain.com/img/stop_hotlink.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

Above code will allow *"Blank referrers"* . To not allow, follow as mentioned in previous step again.

**Note that :**

> In case of displaying image for "STOP HOTLINK" make sure the image is not hotlink protected or your server can go into an endless loop.

```
alloweddomain.com - The domain that you want to allow for hotlink
mydomain.com/img/stop_hotlink.jpg - URL for the "STOP HOTLINK" image
```

**Update :** *[ Block Specific Domains ]*

To stop hotlinking from specific outside domains only, such as blockurl1.com, blockurl2.com and blockurl3.com, but allow any other web site to hotlink images:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)?blockurl1\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)?blockurl2\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)?blockurl3\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blocked\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://example.com/blocked.gif [L]
```

You can add as many different domains as needed. Each RewriteCond line should end with the [NC,OR] code. NC means to ignore upper and lower case. OR means "Or Next", as in, match this domain or the next line that follows. The last domain listed omits the OR code since you want to stop matching domains after the last RewriteCond line.

The last line contains the URL "http://example.com/blocked.gif" which contains the image that will be displayed when the condition occurs.

You can display a 403 Forbidden error code instead of an image. Replace the last line of the previous examples with this line:

```
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]
```

Hope this helped you mate!

Comment: Hey i dont want to allow specific domains and block others i want to block specific domains and allow all other. I see in my logs what sites are using my brandwith there is not many of them. So i prefer the code i am using.

Comment: @c64girl updated the code as per your requirement mate , Find the content after "Update : [ Block Specific Domains ]" title in my answer mate

Comment: It says Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15  :/

Comment: Btw i have problem block this:

Comment: http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=262652596027&t=1475330695000&tid=310&category=20421&seller=jack_trade2501&excSoj=1&excTrk=1&lsite=3&ittenable=false&domain=ebay.co.uk&descgauge=1

Comment: @c64girl u mean you trying to block "vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/.." and failed to do so ?

Comment: @c64girl in that case can you post your htaccess at pastebin.com and post the link here in comment for me to review

Comment: And when i try Your alloweddomain.com and i put 2x domains first with [OR,NC] and other with [NC] none of them show images

Comment: try the above and post your comment mate

Comment: Images still visible. Maybe i block all sites and add those allowed ? I will send You a link to jsfiddle

Comment: I am trying this:

Comment: 'RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?allegro.pl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?supermami.pl [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [F,L]'

Comment: And its not seems to work i am trying to allow only 2x sites to have access to files