# .htaccess allow from localhost to read css and normal stuff

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to with this code or a simillar with same functions, deny every direct access?
At the moment If I access the website it wont load any css or js, I need to allow, but I have no idea how I should allow with `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^(functions/|dist/|includes/|css/|js/) - [F,L,NC]
ErrorDocument 403 https://example.com
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com
```

Comment: What do you mean by "deny every direct access"? Do you mean you want to redirect users that visit any page of your site to the homepage?

Comment: Yes if is css or js pages

Comment: [Prevent Hot Linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846592/htaccess-block-domains-from-hotlinking-images)